# MITM Bluetooth SPP server

Tags: bluetooth, man-in-the-middle

I want to figure out the protocol between 2 Bluetooth devices (BT, no BLE). I know they are using SPP as I can use https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port to connect to the slave.

I was wondering if I could do a MITM attack by emulating the slave so the real master connects to me and to pipe the data through to the real slave?

Does such a tool exist or should I write one myself?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: YES, it is possible. I successfully did a man-in-the-middle attack using [btproxy](https://github.com/conorpp/btproxy). I also used bdaddr to spoof the MAC address.